# ¿Por que en mi input tipo text que formatea los numeros ingresados ej: "1000" a "1.000,00" al actualizarlo se borra todo o conserva 2 o 3 valores?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, ecmascript-6

Este vendria ser mi codigo, lo que quiero lograr es que si una persona al ingresar un valor "1000" al darle tab o salir del campo se formatee a "1.000,00" y si la persona se equivoco de valor ingresado que pueda modificarlo por ejemplo que pueda borrar un 0 de esos mil "1.00,00" y pueda introducir cualquier otro valor "1.200,00" y se conserve la convertibilidad sin que se le borre lo anterior ingresado.
Este es mi código:

```
<input id="moneda" type="text" onkeyup="allowOnlyNumbers(this)" onblur="currencyFormatte(this, 2)">

function allowOnlyNumbers(input){
  const regexCurrency = new RegExp('[^0-9,.]');
  const regexMultipleChars = new RegExp('[,.]{2}');
  if(regexCurrency.test(input.value)){
    input.value = input.value.replace(/[^\d.,]+/g, '');
  }
  const decimales = input.value.split(",", 2)[1];
  const cantidadComas = input.value.match(/,/g) != null ? input.value.match(/,/g)?.length : 0;
  const cantidadPuntos = input.value.match(/\./g) != null ? input.value.match(/\./g)?.length : 0;
  if((cantidadComas != undefined && cantidadComas > 1) || (cantidadPuntos  != undefined && cantidadPuntos > 1))input.value = input.value.slice(0, -1);
  if((cantidadComas != undefined && cantidadComas == 1) && (cantidadPuntos  != undefined && cantidadPuntos == 1)) input.value = input.value.slice(0, -1);
  if(regexMultipleChars.test(input.value)) input.value = input.value.slice(0, -1);
  if(cantidadComas != undefined && cantidadComas == 1 && decimales.length > 2 ) input.value = input.value.slice(0, -1);
}

function currencyFormatte(input, maxLength){
  const entero = input.value.split(/[,.]/g, 2)[0];
  let formattedValue = input.value;
  if(input.value == "0")
  {
    formattedValue = "0";
  }else if(input.value != "" && entero.length > 0 && !input.value.includes(",")){
    formattedValue = Number(input.value).toLocaleString('de-DE', {minimumFractionDigits: maxLength, maximumFractionDigits: maxLength});
  }
  else if(input.value != "" && entero.length > 0 && input.value.includes(",")){
    formattedValue = Number(input.value.replaceAll(".","").replace(",", ".")).toLocaleString('de-DE', {minimumFractionDigits: maxLength, maximumFractionDigits: maxLength});
  }
   return input.value = formattedValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para convertir en el formato requerido basta con hacer lo siguiente:

```
function format(txt){
  txt.value= Number(txt.value).toLocaleString("es-ES", {minimumFractionDigits: 2});
}
```

Lo complejo es validar, sobre todo al volver al input porque, por ejemplo "12.344,34" no es un número valido en javascript, así que al regresar hay que limpiarlo. Además nunca sobra poner algunas validaciones

Aquí una demo con 3 funciones:

1.- `format` que se ejecuta cuando se pierde el foco del control (evento `blur`)
Aquí se formatea el número usando [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

2.- `clean` Limpia el formato anterior a un formato valido numéricamente en Javascipt, es decir sin separador de miles, y con el separador de decimales como un punto

3.- `GetValidNumber` Convierte en valor del input en un número y lo retorna, y si no puede retorna null. Adicionalmente agregué que mostrara un borde rojo si no era posible convertirlo a número.

```js
function format(txt){
 let numero = GetValidNumber(txt);
 if(numero){
    txt.value= numero.toLocaleString("es-ES", {minimumFractionDigits: 2});
 }
}

function clean(str){
  return str.replace(".","|").replace(",",".").replace("|","");
}

function GetValidNumber(txt){
 let numero = Number(clean(txt.value));
 if(Number.isNaN(numero)){
  txt.setCustomValidity("Número no valido");
  return null;
 }
 txt.setCustomValidity("");
 return numero;
}
```

```css
input:invalid{
  border-color:red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onblur="format(this)">
```